# Angular bootstrap 4 select with search filter

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a project in Angular and I'm using Bootstrap 4 with it.

I have a select:

```
<select>
  <option value="one">One</option>
  <option value="two">Two</option>
  <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>
```

When the select opens I need some search filter or similar.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you explain more what kind of search filter are you talking about ?

Comment: I basically wanted an input where I start typing and it will filter the nearest results it

Comment: and from where did you need to use and add input ?

Comment: I want something like what's here...Live Search section: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your question needs improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom input with a dropdown selector. For example:

```js
<div>
  <input type="text" (keyup)="onSeachDropdownValue($event)"/>
  <div class="dropdown-selector">
    <div class="dropdown-selector-option" *ngFor="let option of searchedOptions" (click)="onSelectDropdownValue(option)">{{option}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In your typescript:

```js
options = ['option1', 'option2', 'option3'];
searchedOptions = [];

onSeachDropdownValue($event) {
 const value = $event.target.value;
 searchedOptions = options.filter(option => option.includes(value));
}

onSelectDropdownValue(option) {
  // Do something with selected value
}
```

You can use two way binding to fill the input with selected option with the method you want (tamplate or reactive method).

Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

There are different solutions, three are:

**1. DataList**

A good tutorial is [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/form-control/#datalists):

in html:

```
 <input
   type="text"
   list="datalist"
   [(ngModel)]="currentItemName"
   (change)="addSelectedItem(currentItemName)"
   [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
 />
  <datalist id="datalist">
     <option *ngFor="let item of itemList;" [value]="item.name">
           {{ item.name }}
      </option>
  </datalist>
```

.ts:

```
    // get or define your itemList
    currentItemName: string = '';

    addSelectedItem(name: string) {
      //do what you need with the selected item
      this.currentItemName = ''; // because the function is called on (change), if we do not reset currentItem, it is not possible to select the same item in a row!
    }
```

**2. ng-select**

[Here](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/data-sources) you can find its examples.
After installing and importing you can use like this:

.html:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let selectedItem of selectedItems;">
     {{selectedItem.name}}                         
</ng-container>

<ng-select [items]="observableItems | async"
      [multiple]="true" 
      bindLabel="name" <!-- the attribute of the object that is shown inside the dropdown -->
      bindValu="id" <!-- the attribute of the object that is saved, if you donot add it the whole object is saved, so I would not use it! -->
      [(ngModel)]="selectedItems" <!--stores items that user has selected-->
      [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" <!--only if you are using in a form -->
>
</ng-select>
```

.ts:

```
public selectedItems: items[] = [];
observableItems = data; // the list of the items that are shown in the dropdown (they must be observable)
```

**3. NgMultiSelectDropDownModule**

Check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55136744/21405520), and if the dropdown data is not shown, then check this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71291747/21405520).

Here is what I've done based on the two mentioned solutions in angular 16 and bootstrap 5.

1. install `NgMultiSelectDropDownModule` and import it properly,
2. in .html:

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown
[placeholder]="'Employee privilege'"
[settings]="dropdownSettings"
[data]="dropdownList"
[(ngModel)]="selectedItems"
>
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

3. in .ts:

```
import { FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { NgMultiSelectDropDownModule } from 'ng-multiselect-dropdown';
@Component({
...
    imports: [NgMultiSelectDropDownModule]
})
.
.
.

    dropdownList = [{}];
    selectedItems = [{}];
    dropdownSettings = {};

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.dropdownList = [
            { id: 1, text: 'Barbecue' },
            { id: 2, text: 'Mustard' },
            { id: 3, text: 'Ketchup' },
            { id: 4, text: 'Mayonaise' }
        ];
        this.selectedItems = [
            { id: 1, text: 'Barbecue' },
            { id: 2, text: 'Mustard' }
        ];
        this.dropdownSettings = {
            idField: 'id',
            textField: 'text',
            selectAllText: 'Select All',
            unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
            itemsShowLimit: 3,
            allowSearchFilter: true,
            limitSelection: 2
        ];
     }
```